# please tell me how do i add image view field in sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to save image in sqllite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876116/how-to-save-image-in-sqllite-database)

I follow [this tutorial](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example) and I just want to add 1 new field in this code to browse and upload an image.

How can I do this please?

```
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.provider.MediaStore;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

      public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;

     private EditText Donedate;
     private EditText Notes;
     private EditText Person;
     private  ImageView imageView1;
     Bitmap yourSelectedImage;

     String img;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stage);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Dueby);

      Donedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Donedate);

      Notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Notes);
      Person = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Person);

      imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      Button Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Browse);






      Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });        

       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

       if (extras != null)
       {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         Donedate.setText(extras.getString("Location"));  
         Notes.setText(extras.getString("Notes")); 
         Person.setText(extras.getString("Person")); 


         img=extras.getString("image");
         imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
       }

       Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
       saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
      });
     }

      private void saveContact() 
      {

         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString(),
                  Donedate.getText().toString(),
                  Notes.getText().toString(),
                  Person.getText().toString(), 
                  imageInByte.toString()




                  );
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(), 
            codeEt.getText().toString(), 
            Donedate.getText().toString(),
         Notes.getText().toString(),
          Person.getText().toString(), null


         );
      }
     }











      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  
      imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       switch(requestCode) {
       case 0:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
               String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn,  
      null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();

               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
               String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // file path of selected  
      image
               cursor.close();
                       //  Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
               yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                       // put  bitmapimage in your imageview
               imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
           }
       }
      }







     }





          import android.content.ContentValues;
      import android.content.Context;
       import android.database.Cursor;
      import android.database.SQLException;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


      public class DatabaseConnector {

     private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
     private SQLiteDatabase database;
     private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

     public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

      public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } 

     public void close() 
     {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
     }       

      public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String  
       LocationEd, String Notes, String Person,byte[] image) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("cap", cap);
              newCon.put("code", code);

              newCon.put("Location",LocationEd);
              newCon.put("Notes",Notes);
              newCon.put("Person",Person);
              newCon.put("Image", image);

              open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, String  
        cap,String code,String LocationEd, String Notes, String Person ,byte[] image) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name", name);
              editCon.put("cap", cap);
              editCon.put("code", code);
              editCon.put("Location", LocationEd);
              editCon.put("Notes", Notes);
              editCon.put("Person", Person);
              editCon.put("Image", image);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }


           public Cursor getAllContacts() 
           {
              return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id",  
      "name"}, 
                 null, null, null, null, "name");
           }

           public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
           {
              return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null,  
     null, null, null);
           }

           public void deleteContact(long id) 
           {
              open(); 
              database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
      }










               import android.content.Context;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
      import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

      public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
     super(context, name, factory, version);
     }

     @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key  
    autoincrement,name text,cap text,code text,Location double,Notes text,Person  
    text,Image Blob);";              
     db.execSQL(createQuery);        
      }

     @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

     }

     }










            import android.os.AsyncTask;
      import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
     import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
     import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

    public class CountryList extends ListActivity {

    public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
    private ListView conListView;
    private CursorAdapter conAdapter;

     @Override
     p ublic void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     conListView=getListView();
     conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

    // map each name to a TextView
     String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };
     conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CountryList.this, R.layout.country_list,  
      null, from, to);
     setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
     }


     @Override
     protected void onResume() 
      {
     super.onResume();  
     new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);
     } 


     @Override
      protected void onStop() 
     {
     Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

     if (cursor != null) 
      cursor.deactivate();

     conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
     super.onStop();
     }    


      private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
    {
       DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(CountryList.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
      {
      dbConnector.open();
       return dbConnector.getAllContacts(); 
      } 

      @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
       {
       conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
      dbConnector.close();
      } 
    } 

     @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.country_menu, menu);
     return true;
     }   

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
     {
     Intent addContact = new Intent(CountryList.this, AddEditCountry.class);
     startActivity(addContact);
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
     {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
     {         
      Intent viewCon = new Intent(CountryList.this, ViewCountry.class);
      viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
      startActivity(viewCon);
      }
     };    

      }











         import android.app.Activity;
     import android.app.AlertDialog;
      import android.content.DialogInterface;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.os.AsyncTask;
     import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

     public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID;
     private TextView nameTv;
     private TextView capTv;
     private TextView codeTv; 


    private TextView Locationlb; 
    private TextView Noteslb; 
    private TextView Personlb; 

     byte[] byteImage2 = null;

    private  ImageView imageView2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

       setUpViews();
       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
     }

       private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);

       Locationlb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location_lbl);



       Noteslb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Notes_lbl);
       Personlb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Person_lbl);


       imageView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
          Button Browse2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Browse2);






          Browse2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });        























    }

     @Override
      protected void onResume()
     {
       super.onResume();
       new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
    } 

     private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
     {
       DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
        {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");

         int LocationIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Location");
         int NotesIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Notes");
         int PersonIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Person");

         byteImage2=result.getBlob(result.getColumnIndex("Image"));





         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
         Locationlb.setText(result.getString(LocationIndex));


         Noteslb.setText(result.getString(NotesIndex));
         Personlb.setText(result.getString(PersonIndex));

         imageView2.setImageURI(byteImage2);


         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
     } 


     @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
     }

    @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
     {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());

            addEditContact.putExtra("Location", Locationlb.getText());


            addEditContact.putExtra("Notes", Noteslb.getText());

            addEditContact.putExtra("Person", Personlb.getText());


            addEditContact.putExtra("Image", (CharSequence)  
            imageView2.getDrawable());

            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
       }

     private void deleteContact()
    {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
       }
           }
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate question and first accept right answer of your previous question.

Comment: but  no one answer me plz just tell me how do i ad image field in sqllite applictaion???

Answer (score 0):

1.Image first converted into base64 and then store this string into database 
[This link will be help you](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/)

```
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.a1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
    byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
```

and when you want to get image and setbackground image use

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,image.length);
 imag_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```